# Retag [Laravel-4.1] into [Laravel-4] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Per Jeff Atwood post here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/195355, there should not be 'version tags' unless it is not relevant to earlier or later versions.

For some reason, someone has recently created a [laravel-4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4.1) tag, which serves no purpose over the [laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4) tag. The content/answers are basically identical between these versions of Laravel.

Can a mod please merge the [laravel-4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4.1) into the [laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4) tag? Or we need more people to approve the synonym request here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel-4/synonyms

*(As requested in other tag merge posts, I have domain knowledge on this tag, as I am one of the top "answers" for the [laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4) and  [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) tags.)*

Comment: 148 questions is not that much. Can't we simply retag? laravel-4.1 will be removed at 03:00 UTC if it has no questions

Comment: as in edit each question and remove the tag?

Comment: Yes, I already did some, 127 left but I have laravel-4 in my ignore list so I don't see anymore questions :-)

Comment: I'm doing it as well - down to 110... give me 10mins

Comment: Ok - done - currently 0 questions with the 4.1 tag.

Comment: Ok, now if no new questions get tagged with laravel-4.1 the tag will be removed by the script that runs at 03:00 UTC

Comment: @rene there are no Laravel-4.1 questions - but the tag is still there...